# "cannot load PDB" when running Visual-D project

Tags: visual-studio, d

When trying to run a simple "Hello world" D lang code snippet in Visual Studio (using the visual-d plugin), I see the following error in the logs:

```
D:\mydata\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\Debug\ConsoleApp.pdb: cannot load PDB helper DLL
```

where ConsoleApp is the name of my app. As per [this thread](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/l532to%2424e3%241@digitalmars.com?page=3), the problem should have been fixed in the v0.3.38-1 installer but I still see this issue. I'm using Windows 8.1 with Visual  Studio Standalone/Integrated Shell.

Any help is making this run would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to the Mago debugger as mentioned on [this wiki page](http://dsource.org/projects/visuald/wiki/Tour/Debugger) and the error went away. Since I just want to get a feel of the language, not using the "native" debugging format doesn't bother me a lot, so all is well now.

Comment: Using VisualD just to "feel" the language is quite radical, IMHO. :) I am working on a simple IDE I call DIDEN for now (D IDE for Newbies), which could be used for those who just started playing with D. I will post an announcement to the NG once it is ready to be used. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the latest VisualD installed does not fix the problem, then try the following fix http://stuff.benjamin-thaut.de/D/visualdfix.reg by Benjamin Thaut. Here is what what he wrote on the NG: "*This is for visual studio 2010. If you need it for a 
different version you have to open it with a text editor and change 
"10.0" to "11.0" for 2012 and "12.0" for 2013.*"

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work. I switched to Mago debugging engine and all is good for the time being. Thanks for your suggestion though, +1.